# Variable expansion and escaping in heredoc syntax

Tags: linux, networking, bash, shell-script, expect

I've got the following script to scrape out the arp table of a switch. No matter how I try to escape everything, quote it or otherwise try I can't get it to work properly. The bash line is interpreted by my own shell before it is passed into the Expect interpreter. I want the bash line to be passed literally as is to the switch to be executed there BUT I need to somehow get the $thirdoctet variable expanded at some point and I want the ssh@{ip} to be expanded.

Arista's bash does not seem to like setting variables. I was not able to define thirdoctet=3 within.

```
function get-arp {
echo ${ip}

/usr/bin/expect > arista-arp-dump-${ip} << EOF
    spawn ssh admin@${ip}
    expect "assword: "
    send "password\r"
    expect "localhost>" 
    send "bash for i in `seq 1 5`; do ping -c 1 10.$thirdoctet.1.$i; done"
    expect "localhost>"
    send "bash for i in `seq 10 19`; do ping -c 1 10.$thirdoctet.1.$i; done"
    expect "localhost>"
    send "show ip arp\r"
    expect "localhost>"
    send "exit\r"
    expect "eof"
EOF

tail -n +2 arista-arp-dump-${ip} | grep b8ae | awk '{print $1,$3}' | tr ' ' ',' > arista-arp.csv

sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1 /'        arista-arp.csv > tmp && mv tmp arista-arp.csv 

sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1 /'        arista-arp.csv > tmp && mv tmp arista-arp.csv

sed '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g' arista-arp.csv > tmp && mv tmp arista-arp.csv

rm arista-arp-dump-${ip}

}

get-arp
```

Comment: I made an attempt to fix the formatting of your question; please check it and re-fix as necessary. (Also, I got rid of the UUOC because UUOC; change it back if this gives you major heartburn.) What have you tried to define thirdoctet? And what's with `send "bash for i in ...`? Have you ever gotten something like that to work? Try a script that does that and nothing else.

Comment: It's never worked in a script. Running that bash command directly in the arista CLI works as intended.

Comment: Literally typing `bash` (space) `for` (space) `i` ...?

Comment: localhost#bash for i in `seq 1 5`; do ping -c 1 10.199.1.$i; done
PING 10.199.1.1 (10.199.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.199.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=2.03 ms

--- 10.199.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.032/2.032/2.032/0.000 ms
PING 10.199.1.2 (10.199.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.199.1.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=2.76 ms
....
localhost Yup, works.

Comment: (1) OK, I'm a little surprised, but I'll take your word for it. (2) Hint: don't post things that should be multiple lines in comments. Don't post things containing `\`` in comments until you know how to do it. (3) You're probably having a problem with the `$` (but you knew that already, didn't you?) Can you do something simple like `bash for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do echo buffalo; done` through `expect`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have variables that you expect to be substituted at different times (on different servers even), but you have coded the script so that they are all substituted once, when the bash function runs. A bash here-doc acts like a double quoted string, so all the variables `$ip`, `$thirdoctet` and `$i` are substituted before the text of the heredoc is handed over to the expect command. It seems that you want `$ip` and `$thirdoctet` to be expanded but not `$i`. You'll need to be a bit smarter about quoting.

I would do this:

1. single-quote the heredoc, so that no variables are substituted by the shell
2. export the `$ip` and `$thirdoctet` variables so expect can access them.
3. escape the `$i` variable so it is only substituted by bash on the remote machine
4. you forgot to "hit enter" -- missing `\r` in a couple of send commands

```bash
function get-arp {
    export ip
    export thirdoctet

    # note the quotes: ........................v...v
    /usr/bin/expect > arista-arp-dump-${ip} << 'EOF'
        # use the 'ip' variable from the environment
        spawn ssh admin@$env(ip)
        expect "assword: "
        send "password\r"
        expect "localhost>" 

        # use the 'thirdoctet' variable from the environment and escape `\$i`
        send "bash for i in `seq 1 5`; do ping -c 1 10.$env(thirdoctet).1.\$i; done\r"
        expect "localhost>"
        send "bash for i in `seq 10 19`; do ping -c 1 10.$env(thirdoctet).1.\$i; done\r"
        expect "localhost>"

        send "show ip arp\r"
        expect "localhost>"
        send "exit\r"
        expect "eof"
    EOF
    ...
```